# Why does raise require that you tuple the argument?

Tags: types, f#

In fsharp, the `raise` function has type `System.Exception -> 'a`, but it seems to require that you provide a 1-element tuple of `System.Exception`. Is that just a special built-in syntax thing, or is there something else going on with the types that I don't understand?

Comment: There are no syntactic 1-element tuples in F#.

Comment: A possible source of confusion: parens don't create tuples in F#, commas do.

Comment: A definite source of confusion. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking why I cannot write:

```
raise System.Exception("oops")
```

.. but instead, I have to put parentheses around the expression that creates the exception:

```
raise (System.Exception("oops"))
```

The explanation is that the compiler actually interprets the former as call to `raise` with *two* separate arguments - the first one being an identifier `System.Exception` and the second one being a (parenthesized) string argument. That is:

```
raise System.Exception "oops"
(raise System.Exception) "oops"
```

When you add parentheses (on the second line) you can see why this does not work. That would be valid if the type of `raise` was something like `(unit -> exn) -> string -> 'a`.

This is a general property of how F# expressions are parsed. You can get the same when you write e.g.

```
let rnd = System.Random()
sin rnd.NextDouble()
```

Here, you also need to write `sin(rnd.NextDouble())` because otherwise it is treated as:
 `sin rnd.NextDouble ()`.

Comment: Gotcha. I was confused about the parsing precedence (I guess?) of type-constructors vs "normal" functions.

Answer (score 3):

It's just parsing it that way.  F# parses aggressively, meaning since raise takes one element, it grabs the first complete element and tries to feed it.  In your case the first complete element is `System.Exception` constructor and so it's seeing that's not a match, and quitting.

Therefore you just need to parenthesize it so the compiler recognizes what you want, or another way is to back-pipe it: `raise <| System.Exception "fail"`, or of course you could declare the exception on the previous line if you want to convince yourself that it's not a tuple.